# Dealing with live js scrolltop values on ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I know that this one was asked too much, but I've been struggling with this for two days now, and haven't got an idea of how to achieve this goal.

I have a header, it's absolute and by default it's top property is equal to the window height. Since I have a hamburger website, It's like header is positioned on the bottom of landing slide, or at the top of the first info slide.

When user scrolls to the first slide, header must stick to the top.

On the desktop, I did:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= h && !header.hasClass('sticky')) {
    header.addClass('sticky');
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < h) {
    header.css('top', h);
    header.removeClass('sticky');
  } else {
    // return false;
  };
});
```

And it's working nice. But on iphones/ipads the header gets it's "sticky" state only when scrolling is finished. It means that if user swipes up on it's ios device really hard, he will scroll to the last section and only when scroll animation will end, user will see a header.

Any solution to achieve desktop behavior on mobile?

Comment: Maybe show us the definition of your 'sticky' css

Comment: in less it looks like ``

Comment: in less it looks like 
`header {
    background: @gray;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 10000;

 &.sticky {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0 !important;
 }`

Comment: CSS looks fine (except for z-index of 10000, which is not great practice). I don't think there is any way around this. It's certainly due to the number of events being fired/handled and redraws that have to happen when scrolling fast. When scrolling very fast, does it really matter anyway?